# Large bitwise left shift on unsigned type

Tags: c

Is something like

```
uint32_t foo = 1;

foo = foo << 33;
```

undefined behaviour in C?

Comment: `uint32_t` **is** unsigned. adding `unsigned` is nonsense. And the shift is UB!

Comment: @Olaf what about para 4?

Comment: Note: if `int` was wide, like 64-bit, code would be defined.

Comment: @chux: But then it would not be `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Olaf 3 Code would still be defined as `uint32_t foo` would become 64-bit `int`, then shifted, then assigned to `uint32_t`.

Comment: @chux: Point taken ;-). You are right. I added a note to my answer. Welcome to verify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shift is undefined behaviour in fact. See the standard (C11, final draft N1570, 6.5.7p3):

> ["... If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3).

**Rationale:** Shift operations can behave quite different on different CPU architectures if the shift count is >= the width of the argument. This way the standard allows the compiler to generate the fastest code without caring about border-effects.

**Note:** that things are different if `int` is wider than 33 bits (e.g. 64 bits). Reason are the integer promotions which first convert the `uint32_t` to `int`, so the shift is executed with the (then larger) `int` value. This leaves the back-conversion to `uint32_t` of the assignment, See [6.3.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3), paragraph 1, 2 for this case. However, on most modern systems, `int` is not larger than 32 bits.

Comment: @abligh: No it does not. That is mentioned in the following paragraphs.

Comment: So this means that `foo << 32` is undefined too?

Comment: I could have sworn when I put in that comment it was quoting the second sentence from the next para - the edit history disagrees though! Sorry.

Comment: @P45Imminent: Yes it is (and yes, I sometimes wish it was not, too). See the added rationale.

Comment: @P45Imminent: Just have a look into the standard before you start an argument next time ;-)

Comment: what do you think "If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 x 2E2 , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type." phrase in the very next paragraph means? It implies that `(1u<<(sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT)) == 0`

Comment: @jfs read the section completely **and carefully**, namely p3 which I cited. Next think what `sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT` yields.

Comment: @Olaf I read it multiple times even before I've seen your answer. Why would I leave the comment otherwise? Why do you think p3 is more important than p4 that defines the expected result clearly? It is strange that ((1u<<(w-1))<<1) is well defined but (1u<<w) isn't. (compilers that I've tried produce results consistent with "undefined behavior").

Comment: @jfs: I don't see your point. "Why do you think p3 is more important than p4" - I could turn this around: "Wy do you think p4 is more important?". Your misscinception is they contradict each other which they actually don't. **Both** apply (and that's true for all constraints and semantics in the standard). p4 does not even make any assumption on the max. range of E2, p3 does not make any about E1. p4 effectively says bits not fitting into the type of E1 just "fall off the cliff".

Comment: @jfs And the reason `(1u<<(w-1))<<1` (please use markdown next time) is well defined is simply because both expressions are **not** identical. As mus as `11 / 2 * 2` isn't the same as `11 / (2 / 2)`. But for the shift, the compiler is free to collapse both shoft expressions into the same machine code if the architecture happens to behave like that. Note that many CPUs don't support shift counts of `w` or higher in machine instructions. If they use a loop for multiple shifts (single-bit shift instructuion only), the loops can ignore counts to save code(-cycles).

Comment: @Olaf the point is: the conclusion in your answer while valid, it is not as clear as your answer suggests. I don't find it obvious and logical that ((1u<<(w-1))<<1) is valid but `1u<<w` isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160932/discussion-between-olaf-and-jfs).

Answer (score 4):

This is (apparently) undefined behaviour. From the C standard section 6.5.7 (of WG14/N1256 Committee Draft — Septermber 7, 2007 ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 - effectively the C99 standard):

> 3. The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
> 4. The result of `E1` << `E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` × 2^`E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2^`E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Re 3, this suggests it is undefined behaviour as the value of the right operand is greater or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.

Re 4, As the shift is unsigned, the first sentence applies: If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` × 2^`E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. This would (but for 3) suggest result is therefore zero.

I believe 3 will take precedence over 4, so it is (after all) undefined.

Olaf's answer shows the same is true under C11.

Comment: @Rup sigh, you are right I think. I've fixed it. Though technically speaking it's not entirely evident which takes precedence.

Comment: Actually, 3 and 4 are not contradictory, so you can have both 3 and 4 be valid without issue; neither needs to take precedence. 3 says that E2 must be smaller than the (promoted) width and 4 then gives what the outcome will be. Another way to view it is that `2^E2` can not be represented in the (promoted) type when `E2` is larger or equal than the width. This also explains why it explicitly says for signed that `E1 x 2^E2` must be representable or else it's undefined. There is no overflow for signed types, so what they allow is for an implementation to implement the shift as exactly `E1 2^E2`.